# Parse error, пыха,

Tags: php

Помогите с ошибкой... ((

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or T_VARIABLE in Z:\home\headhouse\www\wp-includes\functions.php on line 1086
```

Установлен **php 5.3**

Вот собственно лайн 1086 :

```
function add_query_arg( ...$args ) {
    if ( is_array( $args[0] ) ) {
        if ( count( $args ) < 2 || false === $args[1] ) {
            $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        } else {
            $uri = $args[1];
        }
    } else {
        if ( count( $args ) < 3 || false === $args[2] ) {
            $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        } else {
            $uri = $args[2];
        }
    }
```

Comment: 5.3  не понимает  ...$args. воспользуйтесь func_get_arg()

Comment: Я так понимаю лучше поставить более старый wordpress - который будет понимать 5.3. Нежели костыли придумывать в каждой строке)) А так спасибо за разъяснение)

Comment: да, безусловно. посмотрите на требования к версии php